# AngularCli Import node module to angular app.module loadChildren

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I want to import my module from node modules.
This node module has routes that I need to navigate too.

**The outcome I need:**

Wire up my app.module to have **loadChildren** from the module in my node modules. TestModule needs wiring up to forRoot so I can lazy load TestModules routes.

TestModule is a dist folder thats been added to node modules using angular cli version 6 built in ng-packagr.

**This is my core app module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestModule } from "test";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
     TestModule,
     BrowserModule,
     RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: "",
          redirectTo: "test",
          pathMatch: "full"
        },
        {
          path: "test",
          loadChildren: "test#TestModule"
        },
     ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**This is the imported TestModule (that is an npm package):**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './containers/home/home.component';
import { LayoutSidebarComponent } from './layouts/layout-sidebar/layout-sidebar.component';

const COMPONENTS = [
  HomeComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: LayoutSidebarComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [...COMPONENTS],
  exports: []
})
export class TestModule {}
```

**This is my core app tsconfig.aoo.json:**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "../node_modules/test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Info:**

When I do an **ng serve to port localhost:4200** I get no console errors and no git command errors.

I'm using angular cli 6 with angular 6, ng-packagr, webpack and iterm for git cli.

Its hard to debug as I have no errors to work with.
It seems like the core app module isn't loading though.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, when you lazy load a module, you must not import it at the same time
Try removing TestModule from your imports in your app.module.ts